# How to have a table of contents include an entry for itself?

Tags: adobe-indesign, table-of-contents

Apparently, just setting the title format of the TOC to a format that is included in the TOC is not enough, so how can I have the TOC refer to itself?

Comment: When you create table contents, leave out the title and add the title in a separate text frame to the TOC page.

Comment: @Joonas That currently seems to be the only way - could you post this as answer so the question doesn't remain unanswered?

Comment: "TOCception": the entry for a Table of Contents is inside the Table of Contents so you can look up on which page to find the Table of Contents. ;-) But seriously: unless this is a special request from an important client (and whom you cannot talk out of it), I'd rather not do this.

Comment: @RadLexus :D The major point is having a PDF bookmark for the TOC _and_ keeping them in sync with the TOC. And legacy, always legacy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is not "really" possible, I chose a workaround:

- remove the TOC title from its options
- manually add the TOC title in a separate text frame before the TOC-frame

Comment: Seven years later, you still can't, although the information is obviously available to the program because the first page of the TOC has a page number.

Comment: @BobBrown "Never change a running system", right? I'd lie saying I miss working with Adobe products 

Comment: I wish **I** could miss working with Adobe products.

Comment: @BobBrown Hang in there, one day...